# Split string into 2 char long arrays

Tags: python, arrays

i'm currently working on a Playfair cypher and got a bit stuck on splitting my plaintext. I need them to be 2 char long, which would be fine `re.findall(r'.{1,2}',plaintext,re.DOTALL)` like this, but i need to compare them to each other and if they are the same character, i have to change the 2nd one, which i couldnt do with this method. I even tried to call each of them a `list` in a `for` loop, it didnt return with an error but didnt work either

Obviously the `char for char in word` and double `for` loops would work but im looking for a bit more elegant solution. Any idea?

Comment: this is example where `range(len())` can be useful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions merely to pair up characters isn't very efficient.  You can obtain the same result with substrings in a comprehension:

```
bigrams = [plaintext[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(plaintext),2)]
```

To find the indexes of bigrams that are identical to their predecessor, you can use zip:

```
dupIndexes = [ i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(bigrams,bigrams[1:]),1) if a==b ]
```

*Although I'm not sure that's what you meant given that the cypher is a bit more complex than that*

Output:

```
plaintext = "Have a banana"

bigrams = [plaintext[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(plaintext),2)]
['Ha', 've', ' a', ' b', 'an', 'an', 'a']

dupIndexes = [ i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(bigrams,bigrams[1:]),1) if a==b ]
[5]
```